# get calling cookbook within chef custom resource

Tags: chef-infra, chef-template

I have a cookbook `my_service` with a custom resource `write_config`.
This resource is called from another cookbook `node_a`.

- `my_service/resources/write_config.rb`:

  ```
  property :template_source, String, name_property: true 
  property :calling_cookbook, String, required: true

  action :create do
    template "/tmp/test.txt" do
      source   template_source
      cookbook calling_cookbook
      owner    'root'
      mode     '0644'
      action   :create
    end
  end
  ```
- Node cookbook recipe `node_a/default.rb`:

  ```
  my_service_write_config 'config.erb' do
    calling_cookbook 'node_a'
  end
  ```

This works fine, but I would like to get rid of the `calling_cookbook` property.

Is there a way to automatically get the `calling_cookbook` name?

### Solution

(Thank you [coderanger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/78722/coderanger)!)
The basic resource `template` seems to get evaluated in the context of the calling (`node_a`) cookbook (?).

- `my_service/resources/write_config.rb`:

  ```
  property :template_source, String, name_property: true 
  action :create do
    template "/tmp/test.txt" do
      source   template_source
      owner    'root'
      mode     '0644'
      action   :create
    end
  end
  ```
- Using it within the node cookbook recipe `node_a/default.rb` becomes a one-liner:

  ```
  ...
  include_recipe 'my_service'
  my_service_write_config 'config.erb'
  ...
  ```

Neat!

Comment: I believe this is not possible, since during the chef-client run the node has a mashup of all attributes, recipes and cookbooks that will use.
There is an attribute node['cookbooks'] with all the cookbooks that the node will use during the run, but this is quite useless for this scenario.

If you are experimenting with custom resources, maybe using templates like this is not the best approach, try sharing the scope of this custom resource and maybe we could find a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is tracked automatically as `new_resource.cookbook_name`. You may need to `to_s` it because somehow it ends up a symbol sometimes but otherwise should be what you need.

Also specifically for templates this is already the default behavior if you just remove the `cookbook` line.